# Syntax error in Ruby script

Tags: ruby

Why am I getting a syntax error in the following code?

```
movies = { Transformers: 8,
Avengers: 10,
Loki: 7,
Chappie: 6
}
puts "__type  add to add movie__"
puts "__type update to ping a movie__"
puts "__type rate to rate a movie__"
puts "__display to see all_"


choice=gets.chomp
case choice
when 'add'
puts "what movie would you like to watch?"
title = gets.chomp
if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
puts "What is the rating"
rating=gets.chomp
movies[title.to_sym]=rating.to_i

puts "you will watch #{title} at #{rating} ratings"
else
puts "The #{title} movie has alraedy been added and its rating is #(Rating}"
end

when "update"
puts "what movie do you wanna update?"
update1=gets.chomp
if movies[update1.to_sym].nil?
puts "movie not found!"
else
puts "movie has been updated!"
end
when "display"
puts "movies"
end
when "delete"
puts "deleted"
else
    puts "Error!"
end
```

Comment: What line the error is poined on?

Comment: You really should indent your Ruby code so it's more readable. I hope you've got that in the original source. When trying to narrow down syntax errors it's often helpful to remove chunks of code temporarily to see if it resolves the problem. We all have days where a spurious `end` wrecks compilation.

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra-`end` before `when "delete"`.

```
end
when "delete"
```

Remove it. You should start indenting your code, so that it will be more evident the error.

```
movies = { 
    Transformers: 8,
    Avengers: 10,
    Loki: 7,
    Chappie: 6
}
puts "__type  add to add movie__"
puts "__type update to ping a movie__"
puts "__type rate to rate a movie__"
puts "__display to see all_"


choice=gets.chomp
case choice
when 'add'
  puts "what movie would you like to watch?"
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "What is the rating"
    rating=gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym]=rating.to_i

    puts "you will watch #{title} at #{rating} ratings"
  else
    puts "The #{title} movie has alraedy been added and its rating is #(Rating}"
  end

when "update"
  puts "what movie do you wanna update?"
  update1=gets.chomp
  if movies[update1.to_sym].nil?
    puts "movie not found!"
  else
    puts "movie has been updated!"
  end
when "display"
  puts "movies"
end # <-- here is the affected end
when "delete"
  puts "deleted"
else
  puts "Error!"
end
```